# Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependency-injection, guice

I am trying to use Guice to resolve dependency injections using also maven to help with my dependencies, and I had this error every time I ran my code. I tried to change of project thinking that maybe mine was the problem but I found out some on Github to try and check if they run but none of them run, I also tried to change the version of the Guice dependency in the pom but I keeps anyway

```
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3976)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4960)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4966)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.validate(Initializer.java:184)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.validateOustandingInjections(Initializer.java:124)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:141)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at com.mvpjava.guicetutorial.assisted.BasicApplication.main(BasicApplication.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.createMethodInvoker(SingleMethodInjector.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleMethodInjector.<init>(SingleMethodInjector.java:35)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.getInjectors(MembersInjectorStore.java:130)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:97)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:43)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @453da22c
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:339)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:157)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:149)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.<clinit>(MethodWrapper.java:23)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @453da22c
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67)
    ... 40 more
```

This is mainly the error that I'm dealing with and this is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mvpjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guiceTutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I would appreciate some help cuz literally I ran out of ideas...

Comment: If you're using Java 16 or newer, you should use a version of Guice that was released afterward, like the current 5.1.0.